# Can I send/receive HTTP requests/responses with a subdomain on a crossdomain.xml file?

Tags: sub-domain, crossdomain.xml

(I'll use website.com in place of the actual domain as to not disclose any specific website vulnerability)

I noticed on a website that their crossdomain.xml file allowed access from another website with this code: `<allow-access-from domain="*.website.com"/>`

I knew this wasn't a vulnerability, but I checked on that domain that it gave access to, and I was able to take over one of their subdomains.

Now I took over m.website.com (it was an expired bucket) can I use it to send/receive HTTP requests/responses? (I don't want to actually take over the subdomain, but I want to answer this question so I can report it)

I was trying to figure this out myself but I really don't understand if it would work or not, since I'd technically be sending them from the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , you can by using flash .

I did that before [Leak the content of page by using misconfiguration crossdomian.xml file](http://abdullah-iq.blogspot.com/2016/11/leak-private-videos-vimeo-bug-bounty.html)

Here is a useful reference that I used  [Exploiting misconfigured crossdomain.xml files](https://sethsec.blogspot.com/2014/03/exploiting-misconfigured-crossdomainxml.html)